# What is a polytope/polyhedron with $O(n)$ vertices each with degree $O(\sqrt{n})$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, computer-science, polytopes

Is there a class of polytopes (preferably polyhedra) where if the number of vertices is $O(n)$, then the degree of each vertex is $O(\sqrt{n})$? By "degree of a vertex", I mean the number of edges coming out of that vertex.

As a non-example, a Hypercube with $O(n)$ vertices has a degree of $O(\log(n))$ for each vertex (which isn't enough).

Furthermore, it would be a great plus if the polytope could be quickly and easily specified in a computer program. I.e. If the vertices were indexed, one could quickly enumerate the indices of the vertices connected to the $i$th vertex. For example, it's very easy say which vertices are connected to a particular one in a hypercube by just enumerating all the bit-strings that are off by one from the bit-string of $i$.

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph for accurate choices of $n$ and $k$?

Comment: I guess that many Cayley graphs share this pseudo-randomness constraint, too.

Comment: [$O(\log n)$ is $O(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Big-Oh is the most common, so I used/abused that notation, as most computer scientists are wont to do. But indeed, I do mean $\Theta$.
@ JackD'Aurizio Thanks, I'll look into it. But so far, I can only find choices of $k$ that yield exponential and linear relations, not quadratic.

Comment: When you say "polyhedron", do you mean 3-dimensional polytope? When you say "degree $\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$", do you mean that every vertex has the same degree? Both at the same time are incompatible, as every polyhedron (3-dimensional polytope) has a vertex of degree $\le 5$.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested into the set of rectified orthoplexes.

The vertex count of the rectified orthoplex, as a function of the dimension, is $2\cdot D\cdot (D-1)$.

The count of edges per vertex of the rectified orthoplex, as a function of the dimension, is $4\cdot (D-2)$.

Thus indeed in the long run the former increases more or less like the square of the latter.

Note that the vertex figure of the rectified orthoplex is nothing but the orthoplex prism.

--- rk

Comment: Isn't the degree $4d-6$?

Answer (score 0):

I try to give you some geometric intuition and some actual coordinates to the answer of Dr. Klitzing.

The "[rectified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectification_(geometry)) [$d$-orthoplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_polytope)" has vertices whose coordinates are all the vertex permutations and sign selections of the vector

$$(\pm1 ,\pm 1, 0,...,0)\in\Bbb R^d.$$

In other words, choose two coordinates, make them $1$ or $-1$, and make all the other $0$. This is a vertex of the "rectified $d$-orthoplex", and every vertex is of this form. It is an easy combinatorial exercise to see that this is indeed $2d(d-1)$ vertices.

The edge-graph of this polytope is the [*line graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of the edge-graph of the orthoplex (also known as the [cocktail party graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CocktailPartyGraph.html)).
The edge-graph of the $d$-orthoplex can e.g. be constructed as the complement graph of the disjoint union of $d$ isolated edges. Its degree is $2(d-1)$. Hence, the degree of its line graph is $2[2(d-1)-1] = 4d-6$.

So indeed, you got a family with quadratically growing vertex count and linear growing degree, which conversely means, that you have an $\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$-growth for the degree if $n$ is the number of vertices.